# Django NoReverseMatch error for Tutorial Part 3

Tags: html, django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views

Hi I've been trying to figure out why I keep getting the NoReverseMatch error in my program but can't seem to figure out why. I doubled checked that my question.id was correct and checked the urls.py to also make sure that there was nothing wrong but I keep getting the error when I add the {% url %}. I have also been through almost all of the other stackoverflow posts and have still not been able to figure out the issue.

Any help is much appreciated!

Index.html

```
    {% if latest_question_list %}
    <ul>
       {% for question in latest_question_list %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question_id %}">{{ 
        question.question_text }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% else %}
        <p>No polls are available.</p>
    {% endif %}
```

Polls/urls.py

```
    from django.conf.urls import url
    from . import views

    app_name = 'polls'

    urlpatterns = [
         url('', views.index, name='index'),
         url('<int:question_id>', views.detail, name='detail'),
         url('<int:question_id>/results/', views.results, name='results'),
         url('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
         url('specifics/<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
```

]

Comment: Please post the full error message.

Comment: https://imgur.com/eW0mcWK

Comment: you probably should replace `question_id` with `question.id` in the `{% url ... %}` tag.

Comment: no that didn't fix it I had actually had the question.id before and was just changing it to see if it made a difference.

Comment: Well the error indicates that `question_id` does not exists, or is an empty string.

Comment: ya so I'm not exactly sure where the issue is..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue. The problem was that the virtualenv was set up in Python 2.7 and I was doing the tutorial that was designed for Python 3.6. Once I updated the python version for the environment and copied over all the files it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be something like `question.question_id`?
In your anchor tag

Comment: do you mean like 'polls:detail' question.question_id because I'm pretty sure id is an attribute of question.

Comment: @AdvaitKulkarni: yes but you write `question_id` (with an underscore), not with a dot.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem so would it be question_question.id or question.question_id?

Comment: Neither. That depends on what attribute you're trying to access and pass to the url method. If you're using the `id` attribute then it would be `question.id`. If you're using the `question_id` attribute, `question.question_id`.